# Raspbian Kernel panic after RTC module .ko - How to unload modules at boot time?

Tags: kernel, rtc

I am playing with the RasClock RTC module.
After baking my own rtc-pcf2127a.ko, and following the tutorial from the website, I got a kernel panic when booting (Null pointer etc.)
Could not find any decent emergency plan to recover my Raspbian, config.txt or cmdline.txt wouldn't help here, would they?
How to disable a stalling .ko or enable emergency shell to sort things out?
Thanks.
BR

Answer (score 1):

Here's two methods you can try; both require you edit files on the SD card.

## Blacklist via `cmdline.txt`:

You can add an instruction to `/boot/cmdline.txt`.  `/boot` is actually the first, small vfat partition on the SD card.  Mount that somewhere and add to the beginning of the text in `cmdline.txt`:

```
modprobe.blacklist=rtc-pcf2127a
```

It doesn't have to be at the beginning, but *don't add a line break anywhere*.   That file should contain one line only, it doesn't matter how long it is.

## Blacklist via a modprobe .conf file

The preferred method for blacklisting is to add a line to a .conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d` (on the second, ext4 partition).

```
blacklist rtc-pcf2127a
```

And/or

```
install rtc-pcf2127a /bin/false
```

The last is needed if some other module depends on it, since blacklisting is not enough to prevent loading of dependencies.  You can create a new file in that directory if you want, make sure to use the `.conf` suffix.

A possible issue with this method is you *may* have to run `depmod -ae` afterward to make it effective, meaning you'll have to use the cmdline.txt method first, to get the system running.  I'd try this one first (without being able to call `depmod`, obviously) just to see.